# Error #2044: Unhandled StatusEvent:. level=error, code= -- No flash on page

Tags: flash

I'm receiving this error, however there is NO flash on the page.  I've used FireBug also to confirm, but only receive this error in IE (IE 8 that I've tested).

Is there something else that could cause this outside of flash?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the reason was due to having https instead of http in the DOCTYPE

Wrong:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Correct:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```